# Removing [Null] Person and Related Hints on Ancestry?

Tags: ancestry.com, hints

This has happened when I am adding people and later realized they are a duplicate (multiple marriages, same mother, same father, etc). When I merged the two people it all seemed okay, until I realized the person who was merged had hints pending. Now the hints are linked to "*,*" and ignoring them doesn't make them go away, and accepting them doesn't make them go away, and trying to delete the null person takes me to the page saying oops, that page doesn't exist. I have 63 pages of hints that are related to 'null' people apparently.

Does anyone know how to resolve this software issue?

My husband and I are 18th cousins which has been part of the problem!!

Comment: I also have 68 phantom links and have had 55 of them for over a year some if them for over 3 years. So some resetting of your system does not resolve the issue . It also is not caused by duplicates . It does say the links are no longer available which could be caused by the system losing that link if it has been deleted or become private but the system is not allowing it to reset it. So it would be nice if it could be tidied up.

Comment: My issue is too many "spousal," or "children," that I do not wish to follow. We all know in the 1700's and 1800's there are MANY children. I get hints for people I do not wish to follow their lineage. I now have hundreds of people I am not adding their name, nor following. These names/people just show up in my hints. That's ok, appreciated through technology, I just want a way to stop those unwanted hints for people I do not want to follow. I want to remove them from future incoming hints
. The notes on Ancestry aren't clear as to how to block/remove/stop those incoming, unwanted hints.

Answer (score 3):

I have some of the same phantom hints in my tree but fortunately only 5 of them.

It is possible that they came from merging duplicates although I had not thought about that being the cause until you mentioned it.

When I contacted Ancestry.com about this or a similar problem about 12 months ago they replied:

> We apologize for the inconvenience created by these hints. What you
>   are experiencing is what we call "phantom hints." These phantom hints
>   appear because of periodic delays in indexing site content and should
>   be resolved during the next indexing cycle, which occurs every few
>   weeks. Thank you for your patience as we try to resolve these issues
>   as quickly as possible.

I *think*, but am not certain, that my phantom hints do clear out from time to time on a cycle that is longer than a few weeks.

I recommend that you contact Ancestry.com via their support pages (under their Help).